# postgresql@13-main.service fails to load but not postgresql@15-main.service - are both needed in linux boot?

Tags: linux, services, postgresql

postgresql@13-main.service fails to load but not postgresql@15-main.service - are both needed in linux boot?

linux - bookworm sid.

So  postgresql@13-main.service is needed ?

Answer (score 0):

by running `systemctl status postgresql*`
i found that the values for lc variables were wrongly set. I changed them to en_US.UTF-8

```
lc_monetary = 'ar.UTF-8'            # locale for monetary formatting
lc_numeric = 'ar.UTF-8'         # locale for number formatting
lc_time = 'ar.UTF-8'                # locale for time formatting
```

in file    `/etc/postgresql/13/main/postgresql.conf`

then I run `systemctl restart postgresql*`
and
`systemctl restart postgresql*`